# iPhone 5/5c/5s family: NFC emulation

Tags: iphone, nfc, iphone-5, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Everybody knows that Apple introduced NFC with their iPhone 6 smartphones breed.

I am curios: are there any ways to emulate NFC on iPhone 5/5c/5s ?

Could it be simulated somehow with hardware iPhone 5-series provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **No**. However, 5/5c/5S users will be able to use Apple Pay if they buy an Apple Watch after they are released.

It's not NFC emulation but users of the 5/5c/5S series of phones will be able to use Apple Pay (the primary purpose of NFC on the 6 series) if they own an Apple Watch.

"While Apple Pay will initially be restricted to iPhone 6 and 6 Plus owners, iPhone 5, 5c, and 5s users will also be able to take advantage of the service if they purchase an Apple Watch after it is released. "

Source Link: http://www.macrumors.com/2014/09/26/apple-pay-roundup/

Answer (score 4):

> I am curios: are there any ways to emulate NFC on iPhone 5/5c/5s ?

**No.** [NFC requires a transceiver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication) that works at specific frequencies, and devices prior to iPhone 6 simply don't have that hardware on board. You're asking something very much like "how can I use my FM receiver to simulate a shortwave receiver?" Answer: You cannot.

Comment: Yep. It's a pure hardware issue, so there is no way to emulate it.